# How to make floating view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, autolayout

What I mean by floating view is custom view that is a subview (or appears to be a subview) of scrollview which scrolls along until it anchors on certain point. Similar behavior would be UITableView's section header. Attached image below

[image: floating view image]

My content view (the view underneath the floating view) is not in tableview layout. Meaning if I use tableview only for the floating view, I have to put my content view inside 1 giant cell or break it to several cells with different layouts. The content view will have a lot of dynamic elements which is why I don't want to put it inside UITableViewCell unless I have to. Can I make floating view programmatically / using autolayout on scrollview?

Comment: This is a **primarily opinion-based** question, please report more details about you issue.

Comment: I met it too before, my experience is using auto layout seems not so good, sometime it has some delay animation, and I use KVO, it 's much better.   by the way , using table view is more easier as you said

Comment: you said _"I don't need a tableview for the page"_, but technically you've excluded the obvious solution to use floating section headers and without showing any effort to present any other solutions, you just dropped a demand here to get your problem resolved by __someone__ else and __somehow__ else – that is not the way how to raise a question here.

Comment: @holex That's poor wording on my part. I did explain why I prefer not to use tableview. I know how to use floating section headers and I want to know if there are better alternatives. I did try to present other solutions asking for recommendations and previous commenter think it's a opinion-based question which is why I edited to straight up "How to" question. Thanks for the suggestions, I'm new here and still learning how to ask properly :)

Answer (score 2):

Using the tableview section header is probably the best solution, you can always easily customise the number of cells or cells themselves to achieve a particular layout.

However if you definitely don’t want to deal with a tableview, this component seems really cool, it's actually is meant to be added to a tableview, but I tested it with the twitter example and you can actually add it to a scrollview, so you don’t need a table view and it will work, give props the guy who made it. [GSKStretchyHeaderView](https://github.com/gskbyte/GSKStretchyHeaderView)

Hope this helps, comment if you have any questions, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use KVO to update the floating view's frame.

Here is the sample code written in Objective-C:

```
// ScrollView.m
// ScrollView is a subclass of UIScrollView

@interface ScrollView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *floatingView;
@property (nonatomic) CGRect originalBorderFrame;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat anchorHeight;

@end

@implementation ScrollView


- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        self.floatingView = [UIView new];
        self.floatingView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.8211 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
        self.floatingView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, frame.size.width, 20);
        self.originalBorderFrame  = self.floatingView.frame;
        [self addSubview:self.floatingView];

        self.anchorHeight = 44;

        [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset"];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"contentOffset"]) {
        if (self.contentOffset.y > self.originalBorderFrame.origin.y-self.anchorHeight) {
            self.floatingView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.originalBorderFrame, 0, self.contentOffset.y - (self.originalBorderFrame.origin.y-self.anchorHeight));
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Here is the capture:

[image]